# What is the complete list of properties supported by annotation @ActivationConfigProperty

Tags: java, jms, java-ee-6

How to know all the set of valid properties supported by Java EE 6 JMS annotation spec
@ActivationConfigProperty

The [Java EE 6 Documentation for @ActivationConfigProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/ActivationConfigProperty.html)
It lists only the standard properties, but what about

1. endpointPoolMaxSize
2. endpointPoolResizeCount
3. endpointPoolSteadySize
4. maxSession

how do we know if the above are even valid?
where to find the right documentation

Answer (score 1):

Per the EJB spec, ActivationConfigProperty are converted into activation spec properties, so the supported properties would need to be documented by the resource adapter you're using.  Most like you're configuring the MDB to be activated by a JMS message, so the supported properties would be documented by the JMS provider.

Comment: glassfish was able to autogen activation spec behind the scenes and it worked without any issues.  However, when I tried to import the war file manually into WAS 8.5.5.5 it was asking for activation spec bindings. I will update this post when I gather more information